# QGIS fails to open from Python script

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to get python script to open QGIS and display a project file from a windows batch file, but it QGIS never opens. What am I doing wrong?

batch file contains (I've used this with another script which works OK):

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\filemanagement\Python_QGIS
SET QGISNAME=qgis-ltr
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
REM Python Setup
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal
"%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\python" "C:\filemanagement\Python_Scripts\QGIS_open_project\open_project.py"
```

python script below:

```
from PyQt4 import *
#from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.core import *
#from PyQt4.QtXml import *
from qgis.gui import *
import math
import os

from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

inqgis = iface is not None
#if inqgis == 0:
path="C:/filemanagement/Python_QGIS/apps/qgis-ltr"
qgs = QgsApplication(sys.argv, True)
qgs.setPrefixPath(path,True)
qgs.initQgis()

# Get the project instance
project = QgsProject.instance()
canvas=QgsMapCanvas()

bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
project.read(QFileInfo('c:/data/qgis_tests/test.qgs'))
#print project.fileName()
```

Comment: @Joseph at this point the `qgs` object hasn't been initialised yet?

Comment: All I get then is qgs is not defined

Comment: @Alex - Whoops, you're right. I tend to use the following: `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`; `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(path, True)`; `QgsApplication.initQgis()`

Comment: I could be completely on the wrong track here but maybe you need to call `qgs.exec_()` at the end of your script